# Pentatonic scales fingering

Tags: piano, scales, fingering

Can anyone tell me how they work these scales fingering?

I work them in groups having the same fingering. For example, one day I practice C, F, and G. My fingering is as follows:

- LH: 3-2-1/2-1
- RH: 1-2-3/2-1

That's for one octave.

I do the same for more than one octave; however, it feels like a little "too much work" compared to standard "classical" scales.

Any insight?

For the black keys, I work a similar system depending on their position, with a bit of adaptation.

*All I do* is always based on classical because it's the source of most music.
Just need to know what more experienced pianists think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really interesting question. I have never thought about this before, but here's what I'm thinking after playing around a bit.

For the white key scales that you mentioned, my first thought would be to use `1-2-3/1-2` (for the right hand ascending) like you have been doing.

I think a feasible alternative would be to use the gap between the thumb and forefinger to travel the gap in the scale. That would mean using `2-3-1/2-1` for the right hand ascending.

If we tried to do "less work" than two turns per octave, I think a `1-2-3/1-2-3/...` pattern works quite well. You'd be matching five turns to every three octaves, though, so it might not be as easy to manage. After playing a while, I like how it feels - it's a fun way to play the scale, and it definitely feels like less work than the other methods above.